# Angular - ng-class based on state

Tags: angularjs, state, ng-class

Any specific reason why my code is not working?

```
<li ng-class="{active : $state.includes('products')}">
```

router code:

```
.state('products', {
  url: '/products',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/views/products/products.html',
  controller: 'productsController',
  controllerAs: 'products'
})
```

Comment: You should add your controller. 
In the controller have your something like : `$scope.$state = $state;` ?

Comment: are you sure that you are referencing your state name correctly? Maybe add your router code to the question

Comment: @M B :added router code as well

Comment: You should use ui.router extensions, it's breadcrumb feature. Check if breadcrumb contains product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to set the `$state` and `$stateParams` on your `$rootScope`, if you do so, you can keep using your first approach on html:

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

This way you don't need to inject them on every single controller.

Here is the reference:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template

PS: I personally don't recommend this kind of global approach, but it has its merits

Answer (score 2):

you will need to get the $state provider via the **$injector** in your controller (as you would inject yourself **$scope** or a **service**.

***EDIT:***

Include it as such:

```
 angular.module('yourModule', []).controller('YourController',['$injector',
     funciton($injector){}
 ]);
```

Then:

```
$scope.$state = $injector.get('$state');
```

You now have access to $state. To get the name of your current state, simply use:

```
 $state.current.name
```

Example:

```
 <li ng-class="{active : $state.current.name === 'products'}">
```